# Converting Double to Short to Byte

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, short

I need to convert a `Double[]` to `Short[]` to `Byte[]`

I'm converting to short first, since `Double` has to many bits so if I convert it directly to `Bytes` I will get blank bytes.

Intially I have a `Double[]` called `wavPuroDer` filled with information

```
    short[] wavShortDer = ConvertToShort(wavPuroDer);
    byte[] wavByteDer = ConvertToByte(wavShortDer);

    public static short[] ConvertToShort(double[] doble)
    {
        short[] shorty = new short[100000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < doble.Length; i++)
        {
         shorty[i]=Convert.ToInt16 (doble[i]);

        }
        return shorty;
    }


        public static byte[] ConverToByte(short[] shorty)
    {
        byte[] bytey = new byte[1000000000];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < shorty.Length; i++)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(shorty[i]);
            bytey[j] = byteArray[0];
            bytey[j+1] = byteArray[1];
            j = j + 2;
        }


        return bytey;
    }
```

my problem is, that im getting a System.IndexOutOfRangeException in the line

```
bytey[j] = byteArray[0];
```

and I cant make this array any larger...

Can someone help please?
 Thanks!

(sorry for my bad English, its no my main language ) 
`

Comment: You shouldn't use `new short[100000000]` you are allocating WAY more memory than necessary and it will be put on the Large Object Heap. You should do `new short[doble.length]` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use linq to simplify all this:

```
byte[] wavByteDer = wavPuroDer.Select(x => Convert.ToInt16(x))
                              .SelectMany(x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x))
                              .ToArray();
```

(Note: just make sure you have `using System.Linq;`)